# Creating HTTP Response object

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-http

While calling a service, it calls API using $http method. In the same service I want to add conditional statement which is responsible to return another success or failure object without calling any API/URL.
Something like this:

> call someMethod()
>
> {
>
> if (statement true) { return httpResponseObject; }
>
> else {
>   return responseObject; }
>
> }

The else part I need to return object `responseObject` in such a way so it can invoke the error block of method which is calling `someMethod()` as a service.

I tried `return false;`, `return -1;`, its not working. Also, I tried using ResponseText of  [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) but didn't work.

Any help, how to create a HTTPResponse object which can be used in same way  just as it would be returned by $Http response object. Something like attached snapshot:

[image]

Comment: you'll need to show more (actual) code than that, as your description of the problem is not clear

Comment: @JaromandaX : I need to create a response object just as it returned by $http response but without calling any API/URL, programatically.

Comment: sounds overly complicated, but as you haven't shown how this function wil be **used**, then it's still unclear

Comment: If you want to fake $http response, you need to return [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) same as $http does. This promise can be either resolved or rejected.

Comment: Use [`$q.resolve`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve) to return a successful promise. Use [`$q.reject`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#reject) to return a promise that is resolved as rejected. For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @bigless I solved by using Promise

```
return (Promise.reject("Error"));
```

It returns same object as it would have been returned by $http call.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple promise and call two functions success, error callback something like

```
someMethod().then(function(){
   //success logic
}, function(error){
   //error logic
})
```

You can fake a promise just like mentioned in comments and then use the above logic.